# Circle formula that touches $X$ and $Y$ axes and passes $(2, -1)$

Tags: geometry, circles

Circle formula that touches $X$ and $Y$ axes and passes $P = (2, -1)$.

Firstly I tried to solve the problem using perpendicular bisector conjunctions. P.B of $XP$ and $YP$ $(X = (X, 0); Y = (0, Y))$ but wasn't probably a good idea and as calculating slopes and finding perpendicular bisectors won't help.

I appreciate some hints on this. Thank you!

Comment: The circle is in the fourth quadrant and with center at $(k, -k)$ and radius $k$. Use point $(2, -1)$ to find value of $k$

Comment: I get $k = 1, k = 5$

Comment: @MathLover Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of circle with $(h,  k) $ as centre of the circle: $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$

The point is in the fourth quadrant $P(2, -1)$
$\implies h = \pm k$ also circle touches touches the axes $\implies |h| = |k| = r$

$(x\pm r)^2  + (y\mp r) ^2 = r^2 \text{ Let } (x-r)^2 + (y+r)^2 = r^2 \text{ put }(2, -1) \implies r^2 - 6r + 5 = 0 \implies r: 1, 5$

The possible equation of circle:
$(x-1)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 1^2$

$(x-5)^2 + (y+5)^2 = 5^2$

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, remember that the $x$ and $y$ intercepts can be given by:

$y = \pm\sqrt{r^2-h^2} + k$

$x = \pm\sqrt{r^2-k^2} + h$

Because the constraint need to be met, the graph only intercept the $x$-axis and $y$-axis once, hence $\pm\sqrt{r^2-k^2} = 0$ and $\pm\sqrt{r^2-h^2} = 0$ as well.

*Note: $h$ and $k$ are constants that come from the equation of a circle, which follows: $(x-h)^2 +(y-k)^2 = r^2$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate it!